# How to translate an "at least one" constraint (in an ER) to SQL?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database, entity-relationship

For my databases class we have to make an ER and translate into SQL.
Our ER is of a library database. How do you translate an "at least one" constraint into SQL? I can't find it on google or in my class notes (I didn't buy the textbook..)
It's represented by the thick line:

[image: The relevant section of the ER]

We're trying to say that each section of the library (Science, Humanities, Film) must be supervised by at least one employee. Here's what I have:

**Employee(pid, sin, salary, address**)

CREATE TABLE Employee

(pid CHAR(9) NOT NULL,

sin CHAR(9),

salary DOUBLE,

address VARCHAR(200),

PRIMARY KEY (pid),

FOREIGN KEY (pid)

REFERENCES Person)

**Sections(sid, name, location)**

CREATE TABLE Sections

(sid CHAR (11)  NOT NULL,

name  CHAR (20),

location CHAR (35),

PRIMARY KEY (sid))

**Supervised_by(pid, sid,)**

CREATE TABLE Supervised_by

(pid CHAR(9) NOT NULL,

sid CHAR(9) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (pid, sid),

FOREIGN KEY (pid)

REFERENCES Employee,

FOREIGN KEY (sid)

REFERENCES Sections)

Answer (score 2):

At least one constraints are problematic for a number of real-world reasons.  The answer is there is no *simple* way to do this.  There are ways to do it however but they are rarely used.  The big problem you run into is one of timing.  You typically are going to require that the supervisor record is entered before the employee, so you can only check the at least one constraint at commit time.  This makes debugging a bit harder.  In essence such cannot work at the *statement* level.

The second piece of bad news is that there is no *standard* way to do this because of the problems noted above, so typically you are looking at doing some extended SQL programming in ways which are not fully declarative and are not fully portable.

In PostgreSQL for example you can write a deferrable constraint trigger which is checked at commit time.  In other databases, the means may vary.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to manage this contraint with your application. There's no standard SQL mean to do this, except with a chack constraint for example, but bad idea here : it will add more complexity than utility.